# Fortus 250mc will randomly freeze up midprint

Tags: troubleshooting

I have an issue where my Fortus 250mc will freeze mid-print. What I mean by freezing is it will stop printing and the LED display will be stuck, wasting all the material and time up until the point of freezing. To get it working again we have to unplug it, plug it back in, and pray that it will finish the print on our next try.

This seems to happen randomly, my boss had the issue during a 30-minute print job for something small and it also happens for very long print jobs (5-10 hours). We originally noticed this happening on long prints where we leave the printer to run overnight, but with a bunch of new projects requiring 3D printed prototypes, we've noticed it happening during the workday as well.

If anyone has any suggestions for troubleshooting or has come across this before I would appreciate the help.